# How to edit a model instance's text field (storing HTML) using markup/down editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(app is built on Rails 4.0.3/postgres)

I have a model defined where one of the attributes is a text field containing the entire HTML of a webpage- I store it as text, which I then set as an instance variable (@html) in the controller and then render it through a view using <%=raw @html %>.  This allows me to store and render entire pages easily.

My question is, I need to allow users to edit the HTML in-browser using some kind of markup language/editor, so how would I go about doing so?  The workflow would be that the user clicks on an instance of the model through a dashboard, and then is able to edit the name of model instance (easy), and under that is able to edit the html attribute and save it via some kind of markup editor like Github's [gist](https://gist.github.com/) editor.  I feel like this should be easy but can't figure it out- can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!